# Wie funktioniert ein Relativpronomen "Dativ Verb"?

Tags: dative, accusative, relative-clause

In meinem Kursbuch gibt es dieses Beispiel, unter dem Titel "*Relativpronomen: Dativ Verb*":

> Wo ist der Lehrer, **dem** ich im Park begegnete?

Ich kann nicht verstehen, warum dieser Satz ist in Dativ.

Früher, gibt es ein anderes Beispiel, unter dem Titel "*Relativpronomen: Akkusativ Direktes Objekt*", wo es sagt:

> Wo ist der Lehrer, **den** sie anrufen wollen?

Mit beiden Satz kann ich auf Englisch sagen "*whom*", daher ist es schwierig für mich, die Unterschied zu erkennen.

Können Sie mir bitte helfen zu verstehen, warum das erste Beispiel "*dem*" verwendet?

Comment: Mit ein wenig mehr Forschung scheint es eine Handvoll Verben zu geben, [die immer Dativ verwenden](https://learngermanwithanja.com/the-30-most-important-dative-verbs-in-german/). Muss man sich nur daran erinnern?

Comment: Yes. German has case inflection, governed by lexical items, and you just have to learn which words go with which case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Im Gegensatz zum Englischen hat das Deutsche nicht einen Objektkasus, sondern drei: Akkusativ, Dativ und manchmal auch Genitiv. Welche Objekte ein Verb hat, muß man lernen.

> Ich **treffe** mein**en** Lehrer im Park. (*treffen* + Akkusativobjekt)
>
> Ich **begegne** mein**em** Lehrer im Park. (*begegnen* + Dativobjekt)

Das Relativpronomen im Relativsatz muß zu dem Verb passen, zu dem es steht.

> der Lehrer, **den** ich im Park **getroffen** habe
>
> der Lehrer, **dem** ich im Park **begegnete**

Für einen Deutschlerner ist es wahrscheinlich sinnvoll, Verben mit Dativ in einer Liste zu sammeln, da Dativobjekte seltener als Akkusativobjekte sind.

1. *helfen, danken, widersprechen, zuhören, begegnen, ...*
2. *gehören, gefallen, passen, schmecken, ...*

Die Verben der 2. Klasse ähneln sich in ihrer Bedeutung: Das Dativobjekt ist typischerweise eine Person, die etwas bewertet oder als Maßstab für etwas dient.

> Die Schuhe gefallen mir. *etwa:* Ich mag die Schuhe.
>
> Schmeckt dir die Suppe?. *etwa:* Findest du die Suppe lecker?

Comment: Statt Verben in Listen zu sammeln, würde ich als Deutschlernender eher typische (vielleicht auch witzige) Beispielsätze lernen (*Das ist der Mann, **dem** ich **begegnet** bin.  Das ist der Hund, **dem** ich **ans Bein gepinkelt** habe. Das ist der Knochen, **den** mein Hund **gefressen** hat. Das ist der Schwanz **mit dem** mein Hund wedelt*). Der richtige Kasus zum Verb muss beim Sprechen und Schreiben ja automatisch kommen. Da kann man nicht lange über Listen nachdenken, die man mal auswendig gelernt hat.

Answer (score 4):

Das Verb *begegnen* erfordert den Dativ, das Verb *anrufen* den Akkusativ. Der Kasus (Fall) bestimmt auch die Form des Relativpronomens. Eine Tabelle findet sich im Wikipediaartikel über Relativpronomen (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativpronomen), unter »Deutsche Sprache«. 
Für deine Beispiele heißt das:

> jemand**em** begegnen: Ich begegne *dem* Mann im Park. Der Mann, dem ich begegne, ist im Park.
>   jemand**en** anrufen: Ich rufe jemanden an. Der Mann, den ich anrufe, ist im Park.